# Encoding issue with filename in MacVim

Tags: macvim, macos, encoding, xxd

**Question**

In MacVim I type `:tabe jäderberg.txt` to open a buffer for that file. The file does not yet exist. My status line displays the file name `jäderberg.txt`. I do `i<C-r>%` to put the file name into the buffer and it puts `jäderberg.txt`. I write and quit the buffer.

Now I run MacVim from Terminal by typing `mvim j<Tab><CR>`. The file opens, but the statusline displays `ja¨derberg.txt`. I type `i<C-r>%` and i get `ja¨derberg.txt`. If in Terminal I type out the whole file name, `mvim jäderberg.txt`, everything is fine. If I type `mvim jä<Tab>` Terminal refuses to complete the file name.

Why is my status line not displaying the file name correctly when I open MacVim from Terminal and tab-complete the filename?

**As far as I've gotten**

"Accented characters" can be stored as a single code point or as a series of code points. I don't know much about this, but I can tell there is a difference between how Terminal treats the character `ä` that I type and the character `ä` that is stored in a file name and completed with `<Tab>`.

Typing `jä`:

```
$ printf jä | xxd
0000000: 6ac3 a4                                  j..
```

Completing `jä`:

```
$ touch jä
$ printf jä | xxd
0000000: 6a61 cc88                                ja..
```

This seems to correspond to a difference between composed and decomposed characters. I don't understand why Vim should fail to correctly display the decomposed `ä` that is actually stored in the file name, and *only when I give the file name with a decomposed `ä`*.

**Observations**

Here are some further observations. I'm not sure what other info is relevant, so ask and I'll add.

1. If I move the cursor over the characters `ja¨derberg.txt` in the buffer, they change. With the cursor on `j` and pressing `l` until end of line, here is how the line changes.

   ```
   ja¨derberg.txt
   ja¨derberg.txt
   jadderberg.txt
   jadeerberg.txt
   jaderrberg.txt
   ...
   jaderberg.txtt
   ```
2. I wrote a function to loop through all characters on the line and convert each to a number and back to a char, then write the results to the buffer.

   ```
   function! JJDebugEncoding(lineno)
       let line = getline(a:lineno)
       let newline = ""
       for char in split(line, '\zs')
           let nr = char2nr(char)
           let newline = newline . nr2char(nr)
       endfor
       call append(a:lineno, newline)
   endfunc
   ```

   When I run it for a line with `ja¨derberg.txt` I get `jaderberg.txt`.

   There is no byte value `228 (ä)` or `168 (¨)` anywhere in the buffer.
3. Terminal Vim does not seem to have this problem.
4. `encoding` is set to `utf-8`. I'm not sure where this option is set since `latin1` is the default, I'm not setting it in my vimrc and `:verbose set encoding` doesn't tell me anything. But I have tested that it is already set by the time my vimrc is sourced (that's why I don't set it myself) so I figure that should be ok. `fileencoding` defaults to `encoding` if it is not set, but I have also tried setting it explicitly before writing the buffer to file with no difference. `fileencodings` is set to `ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1` and `fileformats` to `unix,dos,mac`.

**Edit:**

a.) `NFS+` requires file names to only contain characters in Unicode Normal Form D, that is, accented accented characters are decomposed. Other filesystems seem to favor but not enforce UNF-C, composed. Therefore this is likely a MacVim-specific problem.

b.) I was wrong to say this does not affect terminal Vim. It does, and `ga` with cursor on `ä` gives

```
" typed
<a>  97,  Hex 61,  Octal 141 < ̈> 776, Hex 0308, Octal 1410
" from % register or tab-completed
<ä> 228, Hex 00e4, Octal 344
```

The reason I didn't notice this difference is that terminal Vim renders the characters the same way.

c.) Some relevant and helpful reading

- [vim_mac 2007 related discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vim_mac/filename/vim_mac/VoqFOpI2Yk8/vJSTxcWBeloJ)
- [Comment #2 contains a good explanation of part of the problem](https://code.google.com/p/macfuse/issues/detail?id=139)
- [tab completing precomposed/decomposed characters](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10476/how-to-enter-special-characters-so-that-bash-terminal-understands-them)
- [vim_mac distinguish between the encoding and rendering parts of the problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vim_mac/filename/vim_mac/dRM0cubZb1M/B5N9vf1tOgQJ)

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't reproduce this in Linux Vim or Linux gVim...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thanks for checking, I've done some more reading and it does seem to be a MacVim specific problem. I'll update my question with some links for now and continue looking when I get a chance.

Comment: looks like vim can't handle decomposed characters well. Hm, that might be a bug. You might want to create an issue for that. If you do `convmv --nfc -t utf-8 -f utf-8 j*derberg.txt` does it work?