# Problems with paths that includes swedish characters

Tags: plugin-nerdtree, macos, plugin-ctrlp, version

## Update

I've now also tried this on my Arch setup and everything works fine there.
`vim --version` on that machine says:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Sep 28 2015 08:49:36)
Included patches: 1-884
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      +lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE  -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -lncurses -lelf -lnsl   -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic   -lruby -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm  -L/usr/lib
```

---

## Original Question

I'm having problems with both NERDTree and CtrlP after upgrading to Vim 7.4.

CtrlP can't find any entries in some folders and NERDTree doesn't display all content of all folders. I've had none of these problems before upgrading. I have the same problem when testing [ctrlspace](https://github.com/szw/vim-ctrlspace).

I think that the problem is that the path have Swedish characters (å, ä, ö) in it. Though this weren't a problem before upgrading from the built-in Vim in OS X (El Capitan). If I rename the folders in the path so that there are no such characters, then I don't have the problem anymore.

---

Try the following path while standing in `åäö`

```
åäö/foo/bar:

baz.txt
```

---

My `vim.rc`:

```
" -------- Vundle -------
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

I upgraded using `brew install vim` and this is what `vim --version` says:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct  1 2015 17:36:26)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-884
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         -gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: /usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -F/usr/local/Frameworks -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: /usr/bin/clang   -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -F/usr/local/Frameworks -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -F/private/tmp/vim20151001-44506-3ot6hp/vim-7.4.884/Frameworks -o vim        -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -fstack-protector  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -framework Python   -lruby.2.0.0 -lobjc
```

Comment: what is your vimrc configuration for  NERDTree and CtrlP.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Please describe clearly the error and show any error message.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt "CtrlP can't find any entries in some folders and NERDTree doesn't display all content of all folders." Basically none of the plugins find the content in the folders. The only message I get is "== NO ENTRIES ==" from CtrlP.

Comment: Well, then go and ask the plugin authors.

Comment: I really think this is a problem with Vim (on Mac?). Since it's all about plugins that do something with the path.

Comment: @Oskar If you suspect something like this, you should reproduce the problem without any plugins. I still don't understand, what your exact problem is, so can't help

Comment: For a possibly related **filename+accented characters+os x** problem, take a look at my question http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4497/encoding-issue-with-filename-in-macvim. It has not been answered but it contains some reasoning and links which may give you some ideas to pursue.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt What is that you don't understand? Neither NERDTree nor CtrlP finds the files in a directory where there are files.

Comment: @Oskar then go and ask at their bug tracker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by removing `mac_precompose_path` from the Vim source code.

A fork where this is fixed can be found here: https://github.com/OskarPersson/vim

I tested this by creating a Homebrew formula of the repository above.

Comment: You might want to create an issue at the vim github repository so that this can be fixed with the official vim source.